# Show that Aut(G) is a subgroup of Sym(G).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reading a text and this was the proof that they provided:

> Clearly Aut(G) is a subset of Sym(G); we need to check that it is a
>   subgroup. Certainly the composition of two automorphisms is an
>   automorphism, and it is easy to check that the inverse of an
>   automorphism is an automorphism.

I don't understand it so any proof better than this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that if $g,h \in H \subset G$ then $g^{-1}, Id ,gh \in H$ as well - which is exactly what they show, minus the identity part, which is obvious.